# How can I do Server Side Rendering of reactJS app with Python/Django as backend?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, create-react-app

I have created the reactjs app using create-react-app and have used react-route-dom for routing. I have used Python/Django Rest Framework for the backend.I have used this tutorial to connect React with Django-
https://www.techiediaries.com/create-react-app-django/

Now I am facing issues like I can't post every page with the different previews and titles on social media platforms. Also, I have read the CSR(Client Side Rendering) is not good for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better for you to create small NodeJS/Express server just as a web server for your React app. It will live separately on your REST API for which you can keep Phyton.

If I may recommend create-react-app is perfect for client side apps, but try to look into Next.js for server side rendered apps.